# wordpress main page broken while other pages normal

Tags: wordpress

After I changed the salt key in the wp-config.php file. The main page only shows the contents of the raw key, but the other page is normal. I deactivated all plugins and change the theme to default, but the issue did not resolve.

I tried a false database password intentionally in the wp-config.php file. This time, all others except the main page showed database connections error, but the main page still showed a static page with raw salt key contents.

Any hint about the error? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 house search, I found the problem. For some unclear reason, the default page of my WordPress website switched to index.html. Delete the index.html and leave only the index.php, then the main page was back to normal! Cheers.